# weird character included before this character "§"

Tags: html

Code:

```
<p style="margin-left: 35.7pt;">
            §&nbsp;Your image appearing in the movies shot ... 
</p>
```

The result of this is:
Â§ Your image appearing in the movies shot ...

There is no :before or :after applied to DOM elements. Any idea why this Â character appears?

Comment: Use html entity for that or changing the encoding for your page. Use `&sect;`

Comment: Have you set your encoding in your `head` ?

Comment: Generally if you see something like `Â` it is an encoding issue. It will be because it was rendered as a multibyte character which was then interpreted as two separate characters. Using an html entity is a good solution or you might be able to fix your encoding to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your encoding is not set correctly, the safest way to go about it is to just use the html entity for it

`&sect;` instead of §

So

```
&sect;&nbsp;Your image appearing in the movies shot ...
```

Or you probably need to set the encoding of the page to `UTF-8`

generally speaking, if you are not sure if you can change the encoding of the page, then go with the html entity

Comment: Replacing § with this &sect done the job for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `head`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```